# Build docker image fail : Exiting on user command

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, yum

The Dockerfile is as fellow:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum install git \
    nginx && \
    pip install uwsgi \
```

[The result of executing docker build command build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptAhB.png)

When using yum install pakage, we maybe make choice like this "Is this ok [y/d/N]", I can inter "y" easily in the terminal. But how can I select the choice when I build an image with the Dockerfile ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply add -y to yum.

Example:

```
RUN yum -y install git ...
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you for this.

Comment: what if we have multiple y while installing?